# Stop neo4j from command line on Linux

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to shutdown a neo4j database which is run from an Appimage on my desktop. The official docs specify using: `systemctl stop neo4j` https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/installation/linux/systemd/

This results in the following error:
Failed to stop neo4j.service: Unit neo4j.service not loaded.

How do I shutdown neo4j running from an Appimage from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

```
pkill -TERM neo4j-desktop
```

Using the system to exit neo4j is less elegant than I had hoped (but appears to work without issue).

[Linux: close a program with command line (not kill it)](https://superuser.com/questions/406920/linux-close-a-program-with-command-line-not-kill-it)